# dataTransfer is null when using namespace in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, drag-and-drop, dom-events

I've written some functions in Javascript. To prevent name collision I decided to place them into namespace. It seems to me everything works fine, but `drop` event doesn't have `dataTransfer` object now. Original code is below:

```
var dropBox;

function init(){        
    dropBox = $('#img-container');

    dropBox.bind({
        dragenter: function() {
            $(this).addClass('highlighted');
            return false;
        },
        dragover: function() {
            return false;
        },
        dragleave: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            return false;
        },
        drop: function(e) {
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer; //IT IS NOT NULL          
            displayFiles(dt.files);
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            return false;
        }           
    });

    showDragDropText(true);

    if(window.FileReader == null) alert('Your browser doesn\'t support File API!');     
}
```

After putting it in namespace:

```
var mynamespace = {
    dropBox: null,

    init : function(){

    dropBox = $('#img-container');  

    dropBox.bind({
        dragenter: function() {
            $(this).addClass('highlighted');
            return false;
        },
        dragover: function() {
            return false;
        },
        dragleave: function() {
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
            return false;
        },
        drop: function(e) {
            var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer; //dataTransfer IS NULL!!! 
            console.log(e);             
            mynamespace.displayFiles(dt.files);
            $(this).removeClass('highlighted');             
            return false;
        }           
    });

    mynamespace.showDragDropText(true);
    if(window.FileReader == null) alert('Your browser doesn\'t support File API!');
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: where's the `showDragDropText` function ? can you create a plunkr with the issue ?

Comment: @sirrocco, `showDrahDropText` function is represented here just for example. No need to show the code of it, so you can ignore it. What is plunkr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the solution. I had to bind `drop` event in my namespace like below:

```
    dropBox.bind("dragenter.mynamespace",function(){
        $(this).addClass('highlighted');
        return false;
    });
    dropBox.bind("dragover.mynamespace",function(){
        return false;
    });
    dropBox.bind("dragleave.mynamespace",function(){
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');
        return false;
    });
    dropBox.bind("drop.mynamespace",function(e){
        var dt = e.originalEvent.dataTransfer;                      
        mynamespace.displayFiles(dt.files);
        $(this).removeClass('highlighted');             
        return false;
    });
```

Now it works perfect!